# Manipulating contents of a file for determining deadlock

Tags: bash, awk, sed, linked-list

I've been working on a short assignment to determine deadlocks in database soon after it is identified. For this i will be regularly monitoring the process details once i dump the same to a text file.

After certain manipulation The output file (a miniature version) to be monitored is:

INPUT FILE:-

```
SPID   BLOCKING SPID
23       50
71       46
50       60
60       96
```

This means that process 23 is being blocked by process 50 and in turn by 60.
So in this case the process chain dependency is 23->50->60->96 and the other 71->46
In short I want the final culprit spids.. in this case 96 and 46 along with the chain count ( 4 and 2)

OUTPUT FILE:-

```
   CULPRIT SPID   CHAIN_COUNT

1) 96                4  
2) 46                2
```

For this the entire file will have to be looped and compare column 2 matching with any column 1 in the file,. This has to be repeated over until there is no match for column 2

I need to acheive this via awk or sed, however I believe this can be achieved via linked 
list.

Any kind of suggesstion are welcom

****JS just one more question, for sample file

```
SPID   BLOCKING SPID
45       11
12       34
34       35
23       60
71       45
60       71


OUTPUT I RECEIVE:

71=>45
23=>60->71
12=>34->35

OUTPUT I AM SUPPOSED TO GET

23=>60=>71=>45
12=>34->35
```

I hope you got what I am trying to say.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph

Comment: You need to give it a try and come back when you have some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to solve this in two steps. Step one is where we shall create the chain using your input file (assuming that it might be useful for you to go back and check the trail) :

```
awk '
NR>1 {
  for(value in values) {
    if ($1 == values[value]) {
      chain[$1] = chain[value] "->" $2;
      values[$1] = $2;
      delete chain[value];
      delete values[value];
      next
      }
    }
  values[$1] = $2; 
  chain[$1] = $1 "->" $2
}
END {
  for(left in values) {
    for(c in chain) {
      x = split(chain[c],t,/->/)
        if (left == t[x]) {
          chain[left] = chain[c] "->" values[left]
          delete chain[c]
          values[left]
        }
      }
    }
  for (trail in chain) print chain[trail]
}' file
```

For your input file, this gives the output as:

```
23->60->71->45->11
12->34->35
```

Now we will pipe our above script to another `awk` for formatting.

```
awk -F'->' '
BEGIN {
  OFS="\t"; 
  print "CULPRIT SPID", "CHAIN_COUNT"
}
{
  print $NF, NF
}'
```

This will give the output as:

```
CULPRIT SPID    CHAIN_COUNT
11               5
35               3
```

As I said before **assuming you need to look at the trail**. If trail is of no use to you then you can simply do the following:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  OFS="\t"; 
  print "CULPRIT SPID", "CHAIN_COUNT"
}
NR>1 {
  for(value in values) {
    if ($1 == values[value]) {
      chain[$1] = chain[value] FS $2;
      values[$1] = $2;
      delete chain[value];
      next
    }
  }
  values[$1] = $2; 
  chain[$1] = $1 FS $2
}
END {
  for(left in values) {
    for(c in chain) {
      x = split (chain[c],t)
      if (left == t[x]) {
        chain[left] = chain[c] FS values[left]
        delete chain[c]
        values[left]
      }
    }
  } 
  for(v in chain) {
    num = split(chain[v], culprit)
    print culprit[num], num
  }
}' file
```

Output will be:

```
CULPRIT SPID    CHAIN_COUNT
11               5
35               3
```

You can re-direct it to an output file as you please.

Comment: **JS just check the edited version of question, thanks a lot in advance